# Unable to bind Jolokia JVM agent with my PID

Tags: java, jmx, jolokia

- We are unable to attach the JVM agent to pid of flink process with
  jmx enabled on it.
- We are using java 1.8, java hotspot is enabled, and doing it with
  the same UID (sudo) only.
- Also there are no other agents attached to that process.
- Also we have restarted the process n number of times and tried
  that.
- when i give list option with the agent it shows this process in the
  list.
- Yet we are not able to bind the JVM agent with that process.

Error:

1. > Invocation Target class com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine
   >       command:start : null
2. > Invocation Target class com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine
   >    command:status : null

[image: jolokia-issue-error-snapshot]

Comment: Try to run jolokia with --verbose option to see stacktrace.

Comment: Are you really sure that the process you want attach to is running as root ? Remember, you must be the very exact user under which the process is running. Being root via sudo is not good enough (as mentioned in the docs).

Comment: Issue is already Solved.Thank you guys

Comment: And the solution was?

Comment: By running the jolokia as the same user as my process is running with, i was able solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using the JRE which doesn't have required attach API in its runtime class path ? Try launching the agent installer with the full JDK java executable, or add tools.jar to the class path.